# Disable window offset when keyboard appears for ios app

Tags: ios, qt

Disable window offset when keyboard appears for ios app

I would like to disable the window offset when the keyboard appears for the ios app. For an android app, this is done via `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity ... android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

When the keyboard appears, the components do not move from their places.
Is it possible to get this behavior for ios?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here in the comments:
**iOS Make window-scrolling optional for Items**
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80790
(this workaround works well for me)

========================

***Adrian Eddy* added a comment - 11 Apr '20 01:44 - edited**

*I found a workaround that works with QML . The idea is to install an event filter on QQuickItem and listen for a QEvent::InputMethodQuery with Qt::InputMethodQuery::ImCursorRectangle. Then we set its value to empty QRectF and Qt will no longer scroll the view to show that text field.*

*in C++ prepare a class and expose it to QML:*

```
class Api : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
....
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE void setupImEventFilter(QQuickItem *item) {
        static thread_local ImFixer imf;
        item->installEventFilter(&imf);
    }
}
```

*// somewhere in main():*

```
   view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("api", new Api());
```

*We'll need the actual event filter too:*

```
class ImFixer :
    public QObject {
        Q_OBJECT
    protected:
        bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override {
            if (event->type() == QEvent::InputMethodQuery) {
                QInputMethodQueryEvent *imEvt = static_cast<QInputMethodQueryEvent *>(event);
                if (imEvt->queries() == Qt::InputMethodQuery::ImCursorRectangle) {
                    imEvt->setValue(Qt::InputMethodQuery::ImCursorRectangle, QRectF());
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
        }
    };
```

*Finally in QML add:*

```
TextField {
    id: tf;
...
    Component.onCompleted: api.setupImEventFilter(tf);
}
```